# Error al refrescar desde el navegador, perdida de rutas ionic

Tags: angular, ionic, cordova

Buenas tengo estoy creando una web/app con **Ionic**, todo va perfecto, en modo desarrollo desde live reload, cuando compilo la app también va perfecta, el problema que cuando compilo la web y la subo a firebase hosting, va perfecto hasta que refresco la web desde el navegador, ya no me navega entre rutas, le paso un vídeo que se ve mas claro el fallo.

[Video demostracion](https://youtu.be/ltIbALUV0Rk)
Toda ayuda es de agradecer.

Comment: Hola, por favor pon algo de código para poder ver en que esta fallando, aparte de la demostración que hiciste. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución, es la siguiente: { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }